# Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Prove that $ngN=gN$ for all $n\in N$, $g\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Prove that $ngN=gN$ for all $n\in N$, $g\in G$

---

$$
\begin{aligned}
(n_1*g_1)n_2&=(g_2*n_3)*n_2
          \\  &=(g_2*n_3)*n_2
            \\&=g_2(n_3*n_2)
            \\&=g_2(n_4)
\end{aligned} $$

---

*using [wiki def](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup).does this work? more elegant way??*

Comment: $ngN=gN$ if and only if $(ng)^{-1}g \in N$, which is true since $N$ is normal.

Comment: That's a good comment, that would be worth posting as an answer.

Comment: Slight variation: a subgroup $N$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $aN = Na$ for all $a \in G$. Applying this to $a = ng$, we see that $(ng)N = N(ng) = (Nn)g = Ng = gN$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of equality of cosets (coming from the equivalence relation), $gN = ngN$ if and only if $g^{-1}ng \in N$.  But this is exactly the definition of normality (closed under conjugates).

Answer (score 0):

**Definition.** A subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is said to be *normal* if

$$ Na = aN $$
for every $a \in G$.

*Proof.* Let $n \in N$, $g \in G$ be arbitrary.

Suppose $x \in ngN$, i.e., $x = ngn_1$ for some $n_1 \in N$. By construction, $ng$ is an element in $Ng$. But $Ng = gN$, so $ng \in gN$, or $ng = gn_2$ for some $n_2 \in N$. Then
$$
ngn_1 = gn_2n_1 = gn_3 \in gN
$$
where $n_3 = n_2n_1 \in N$, since $N$ is a subgroup. Thus, $ngN \subseteq gN$.

Now, let $x \in gN$, i.e., $x = gn_1$ for some $n_1 \in N$. But also $gn_1 = nn^{-1}gn_1$. Note again that $n^{-1}g \in Ng = gN$ by construction. So $n^{-1}g = gn_2$ for some $n_2 \in N$. Then
$$
gn_1 = nn^{-1}gn_1 = ngn_2n_1 = ngn_3 \in ngN
$$
where $n_3 = n_2n_1 \in N$, since $N$ is a subgroup. Thus, $gN \subseteq ngN$.

We have shown $ngN \subseteq gN \subseteq ngN$, so it must be that $ngN = gN$ for all $n \in N, g \in G$. $\quad \square$

**Note:**
A quicker way to do this is to just say
$$ngN = (nN)(gN) = N(gN) = gN,$$
but I think the above proof may be more comprehensive :)